# How to Get User List with Role From IdentityUser using .net core and AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Hi I want to Get the Identity User List with Role using .NET core and Auto Mapper (Create Map)
Each User Have Only one Role, I want to Return the List With Each User Role,Iam Using Auto Mapper To Map   
This is the List I want to be Generated

```
| Display Name | User Name |        Email       | Role  |   Department   |
|:------------:|:---------:|:------------------:|:-----:|:--------------:|
| Admin        | Admin123  | admin123@gmail.com | Admin | System Defined |
```

This is the Query

```cs
public async Task<Result<PagedList<AppUserDto>>> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    var query = _context.Users
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).ProjectTo<AppUserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .AsQueryable();         

    return Result<PagedList<AppUserDto>>.Success(
        await PagedList<AppUserDto>.CreateAsync(query, request.Params.PageNumber, request.Params.PageSize)
    );
}
```

```cs
public class AppUserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentNameE { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```cs
CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.DepartmentNameE, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FDSDepartments.DepartmentNameE));
```

AppUser Class

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual FDSDepartments FDSDepartments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Irfan Arif, so what's your problem here? The automapper cannot map correctly or the query cannot achive your requirement?

Comment: Hi, I cant Access the Identity Role and Identity User Role Table to Get The Role of Each User

Answer (score 0):

You can get this data from `Role` table(if you don't have it, you must create a role class and inherit from asp role class like `AppUser`):

Change query to this:

```
public async Task<Result<PagedList<AppUserDto>>> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {

                var query = _context.Roles.
                OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).ProjectTo<AppUserDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .AsQueryable();         

                return Result<PagedList<AppUserDto>>.Success(
                    await PagedList<AppUserDto>.CreateAsync(query, request.Params.PageNumber, request.Params.PageSize)
                );
            }
```

Change map config to this:

```
CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DepartmentNameE, o => o.MapFrom(s => s. AppUser.FDSDepartments.DepartmentNameE))
            .ForMember(d => d.RoleName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Role.Name));
            //populate other properties like above
```

Comment: Give there Error  "Missing map from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String] to Application.Admin.User.AppUserDto. Create using CreateMap<IdentityUserRole`1, AppUserDto>."  When i create the map   CreateMap<IdentityUserRole, AppUserDto>();  the IdentityUserRole Give error Using the generic type 'IdentityUserRole<TKey>' requires 1 type arguments [Application]

Comment: Try to populate the model without mapper to find out the problem.
Add `.Select(x=>new AppUserDto { //here })` instead `ProjectTo`. @IrfanArif

Comment: Can not access the UserRoles , var query = _context.Users.
               OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).Select(x => new AppUserDto
               {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   DisplayName = x.DisplayName,

               })
               .AsQueryable();

Comment: Why you don't have access UserRoles? see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-all-user-navigation-properties). @IrfanArif